# Power Query - Append Variable Dates to Existing Table as Headers

Tags: list, date, append, powerquery

I am having an issue w/ my below M Code. I have set up an simple example of what i am trying to do below, but know the issue is when try to append variable dates as headers into the table:

```
let
Set up steps.
.
.
.
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Other Columns",Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Transpose(Table.FromList(List.Dates(Date.StartOfWeek(DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),  Day.Sunday), 52, #duration(7,0,0,0)), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Dates"}, null, ExtraValues.Error)),[PromoteAllScalars=true])})
in
    #"Appended Query"

Error:
Expression.Error: 2 arguments were passed to a function which expects 1.
Details:
    Pattern=
    Arguments=List
```

The table starts like table A. I use some simple query functions to get to this point. But I need to add the columns w/ dates and the function (Table A: Total Qty/50) for all added date columns as in Table B.

```
Table A                         
Product Table A: Total Qty                      
a       323000                      
b       898807                      
c       844945                      
d       36330                       
e       281009                      
f       611092                      
g       633217

Table B                         
Product Table A: Total Qty  6/4/2017    6/11/2017   6/18/2017   6/25/2017   7/2/2017    7/9/2017
a       323,000             6,460       6,460       6,460       6,460       6,460       6,460
b       898,807             17,976      17,976      17,976      17,976      17,976      17,976
c       844,945             16,899      16,899      16,899      16,899      16,899      16,899
d       36,330              727         727         727         727         727         727
e       281,009             5,620       5,620       5,620       5,620       5,620       5,620
f       611,092             12,222      12,222      12,222      12,222      12,222      12,222
g       633,217             12,664      12,664      12,664      12,664      12,664      12,664
```

Hope you can help! Thanks in advance!
Alex

Comment: maybe you could split out the different commands into their own respective rows instead of cramming everything into one huge nested formula. That way you would know which expression causes the error. The error message shows what the problem is, but not in which function it occurs, so break it down step by step.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your rely. I have been researching this. The issue is most certainly w/ adding the [PromoteAllScalars=true] in the Table.PromoteHeaders function. I tried this link from Microsoft and got the same error: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt260804.aspx)

Comment: Hmm, I don't get any error when I use that example. What version of Power Query are you using?